# Recent Job Change details to be mentioned in UK Standard Visa Application cover letter

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I am showing payslips from past 6 months along with bank details as a proof of regular income. However, 3 months back I  joined a new organization. There was not a single day gap between my jobs.

While showing payslips from last 6 months as well as salary bank account details, should I mention that I have a salary account was changed from Bank "A" to Bank "B", and so I am attaching details of both?

1. Bank Account A - Salary account till May 2017
2. Bank Account B - opened in June and actively credited with salary.

Same query goes to payslips details as well.

Payslips from company A - till April, received May salary along with full and final in June.

Payslips from company B - from June - current months.

Comment: Please also see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105). While it does not directly answer your question, it provides a background about the need for "proof of funds" and what exactly they are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @RedBaron, I read it and I am attaching already. Just curious should I write that I am attaching two bank statements/payslips as my salary account as well as company got changed in past 6 months? (I mean should I mention explicitly?)

Comment: I doubt you're going to find an official source for such a particular situation. However as Gayot Fow confirms, best practice would be to have a well written cover letter addressing this and other issues which are not readily apparent.

Comment: Ok, Sure will follow the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mentioning all the details, you can add the following documents:

1. Appointment letter of the current company [which needs to have the joining date]
2. Pay Slips of the current company [3 months]
3. Pay slips of the previous company [prev. 3 months]
4. NoC letter from your current company
5. Bank statements of both the banks for the previous 6 months

I have had a job change recently too. So, I submit my appointment letter along with the bank statements for my visa applications, so that the multiple banks in my statements are answerable.

> Should I mention that, I have salary account was changed from Bank "A"
>   to Bank "B", and so I am attaching details of both?

The appointment letter should be able to explain that to the visa officer. However, as an extra precaution, add a one-liner in your statement of purpose, saying that you have attached 2 pay slips and 2 account statements due to a recent job change.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dawny33, attached the same, will also mention in letter.

Comment: I had attached the same and also mentioned in my cover letter. Received Visa. Thank you so much for all guidance.

Comment: @ItiTyagi Cheers!  How many days did it take for processing? I applied again 2 days back. Heard that the processing time became less than 20 days these days?

Comment: It took exactly 10 working days, applied on 5th September, received email of decision on 19th, message from vfs on 21st to come and collect.